Build failed with an exception ':image_compression_flutter:parseDebugLocalResources'
I am trying to run
flutter build apk

but I get this Error everytime
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':image_compression_flutter:parseDebugLocalResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':image_compression_flutter:androidApis'.
   > Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\dinsa\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-30\android.jar.
         > C:\Users\dinsa\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-30\android.jar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 38s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

can someone have solution, because I didn't find the solution for this Error
I try everything like
I changed something on build.gradle like some people sead
and I did this
flutter clean
flutter pub get  


